git rollback branches and apply fix later
I read many topics but I am still in doubt.
I have 2 branches with these commits they are on remote repositoy:
master

commit04
commit03
commit02
commit01

develop

commit04
commit03
commit02
commit01

I want to back master and develop to "commit02" but I also want to keep the others commits in another branch to fix it and merge again to develop and master. I can not discard these changes.
I thought about doing this:
git checkout master
git checkout -b fix-branch

Set master to correct commit
git checkout master
git reset --hard commit02
git push --force origin master

Set develop to be equals master (will the wrong code be discarded)?
git checkout develop
git merge master
git push origin develop

Now I can work and create new commits on fix-branch
commit06
commit05
git push origin fix-branch

Imagine the develop is also receiving new commits.
commit07
git push origin develop

Update fix-branch with develop before merging back to develop.
git checkout fix-branch
git rebase develop

Now I have to merge all commits into develop
git checkout develop
git merge fix-branch

So my develop should have all commits
- commit06
- commit05
- commit07
- commit04
- commit03
- commit02
- commit01

Finally, merge develop to master
git checkout master
git merge develop

Is it the best way?
A lot of people says that doing "git push --force" is a bad practice because of the history.

This part is right:
git checkout master
git checkout -b fix-branch


Set master to correct commit

git checkout master
git reset --hard commit02
git push --force origin master

What follows is incorrect:

Set develop to be equals master (will the wrong code be discarded)?

git checkout develop
git merge master
git push origin develop

Nope, merging won't make "develop to be equals master". The way to make them equal is to point them to the same commit:
git checkout develop
git reset --hard master
git push --force origin develop

I didn't understand what you said after that; what we've done up to this point has done what you basically wanted:

I want to back master and develop to "commit02" but I also want to keep the others commits in another branch

You've done that. What you do with the commits you've saved by setting the branch name fix-branch is up to you, but the point is, they will not be lost.

A lot of people says that doing "git push --force" is a bad practice because of the history

You can't make an omelette without breaking eggs. The premise of your question is that you intend to rewrite history. After you do that, pushing with force is the only way to push the rewritten branches that also exist on the remote.
Finally, keep in mind that everything you're doing here is undoable, thanks to the reflog. So just try it!

I am a bit confused on that commit 7 on dev. Is your primarly goal to fix bugs in your commit 03 and 04? In that case I would directly create a new branch for it from master only for this purpose. This branch targets the bugfix and not receive commit7 which seems a bit unrelated to me. For the mean time you can git revert or reset master and same for dev.
Is commit7 a finished feature? Then you can merge it to master instead of dev. If you now finished your bugfixes on the bugfix branch, you can merge the bugfix branch with master.
Some more things maybe worth consideration: If both commit 3 and 4 form a single bug, you may consider to squash the fix to one commit or maybe even amend them. If commit 3 and 4 introduce independent bugs and you can revert the changes everywhere else, then you can consider to use rebase to fix commit 3 first and then fix commit 4 (and maybe squash afterwards).

Note up front: Don't use --force. Instead, use --force-with-lease, which provide a bit more safety against overwriting changes.
Now, let's assume the commit SHA of "commit 2" (the one you want to revert to) is abcd1234. Then, you can reset the remote master branch using:
git push --force-with-lease origin abcd1234:master

Similarly, you can reset origin/develop. For your local branches, you can use this if you want:
git checkout master
git reset --hard abcd1234

Alternatively, you can just keep those local branches as they are to work on. That would be an alternative to first saving the commits after "commit 2" in a separate branch.
